# map is undefined when loop Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I fetched some data in the redux state. All working well. But when It's time to loop over that data, I'm getting the message: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

It's seems the map loop is triggered when page renders and the redux state is still empty (even before the data fetch is completed). So I'm actually looping over an empty redux state.

How am I suppose to fix it? How can I trigger the loop after the data fetch is completed? Any clue?

Comment: Hi, can you share the relevant code and, possibly, post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: Anyway, a very generic solution is to check that the array exist before trying to loop through it (`if (arr) { arr.map(item => { //... }); }`) or to provide and empty array, in case the array does not exist (`(arr || []).map(item => { //... })`)

Comment: Please add your code.